# VBA code for opened word document with print pop up message

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm new to VBA coding. I'm working on a project. In that I need to print an already opened word document with print page pop up to default PDF option. Can someone help me out on this?

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. This is not an [MCVE].

Comment: I'm assuming you want to save the open file as PDF so I have included an Answer below that will do that and still allow the user to decide where to save it. If that is not a correct assumption, I will delete the answer and then please be more specific about your question. For example, provide a screenshot of what dialog you are trying to control.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    With Application.Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
    .Format = word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF
    .Show
    End With
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on my tests, please try the code as below:

VBA code:

```
Sub popUpTo_PDF_Option()
  Dim dlg As Dialog
  Set dlg = Dialogs(wdDialogFilePrint)
  dlg.Show
End Sub
```

Hope it helps you.

Thanks,

Yuki

Comment: How does your proposal default the dialog to the PDF file format?

Comment: When the dialog box pops out,please choose "OK" then it will be automatically saved as the default type of "*.pdf".

Comment: Hello Yuki, Thanks for your answer. I'm getting an error for this (Sub or Function not defiened). Please help me out on this.

Comment: There, it is stated that one must create the new macro by selecting Developer -> Macros, typing a new macro name, and clicking "Create". Creating the macro in this way, you were able to run it.